# How to sort strings in OQL

Tags: java, visualvm, oql

I have tried:

```
select sort(obj.displayName, 'lhs < rhs') from my.org.BusinessClass obj
```

and

```
select sort(obj.displayName, 'lhs.toString() < rhs.toString()') from my.org.BusinessClass obj
```

Both give me character array results, but none of them are sorted by String. I think it's sorting by object id.

I have also tried:

```
select sort(obj.displayName, lhs < rhs) from my.org.BusinessClass obj 
select sort(obj.displayName, lhs.toString() < rhs.toString()) from my.org.BusinessClass obj
```

But these result in errors because sort second argument is suppose to a string expression.

The examples on the VisualVM documentation are only for numbers: 
[Analyzing a Heap Dump Using Object Query Language (OQL)](https://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html)

The class is structured as follows:

```
package my.org;
public class BusinessClass {
    private String displayName;
    // rest of class omitted for brevity 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround I used:

1. Increase the max number of rows returned by OQL

   1. (see: [Increasing the Max Size of OQL Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166290/increasing-the-max-size-of-jvisualvm-oql-resultset) )
2. Copy and paste the result of the unsorted query to a text file
3. Use vim or similar text processor to remove the object id
4. sort using unix sort

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following query to sort strings in OQL:

```
select sort(heap.objects('java.lang.String'), 'lhs.toString().localeCompare(rhs.toString())')
```

in your case use this OQL query to sort your business object by displayName:

```
select sort(heap.objects('my.org.BusinessClass'), 'lhs.displayName.toString().localeCompare(rhs.displayName.toString())')
```

if you want to see your business object and actual displayName in the output use this OQL query:

```
select map(sort(heap.objects('my.org.BusinessClass'), 'lhs.displayName.toString().localeCompare(rhs.displayName.toString())'), 'toHtml(it)+" "+it.displayName.toString()')
```

Comment: I tried `select sort(obj.displayName, 'lhs.toString().localeCompare(rhs.toString())') from my.org.BusinessClass obj` but it still seems to sorting by object id instead of the string contents. Does it seen to be heap.objects('java.lang.String') ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use heap.objects(). I updated my answer above to exactly match your case.